# Select event in FullCalendar programmatically

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

In FullCalendar [in week view](https://fullcalendar.io/#demos), with touch screens (emulate touch screen to reproduce), it's possible to select event with long-touch. The delay can be configured through [`eventLongPressDelay`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLongPressDelay). Selected event has `className` `'fc-event-selected'`. And it displays dots, that can be used to adjust end-time.

I want to programmatically make event selected. E.g.

```js
select(event.id)
```

I've tried to add className to event - it displays event as selected, but dots aren't working. So it's impossible to drag and drop top/bottom edge of event.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4513) about that, but it's still unresolved. I think there may be a way to use this internal API externally.

On screenshot you can see two dots on top and bottom edges of event. They allow to drag and drop start/end time edge. It's default dots, that appear only on touchscreens after long-touch on event.

[image: Selected event]

Comment: "dots aren't working"...it's not clear what you mean. What dots do you mean, and what do you want them to do?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wonder if something like this would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664703/simulate-long-press-in-javascript