# How to emulate long press or right click Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on writing a script on browser web pages. I need to trigger right click event or a long press event on an HTML element.

I have figured out how to click on an element through the click() method. But now i need to trigger a right click or a long press.

Here is the code:

```
 let div = document.querySelector(".scrollViewport");
    let chats = div.children[0].children[0].children;
    chats[index].children[0].children[0].click();
```

Any help?
Thanks,

Comment: This is two questions in one. Right click simulate in JS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914684/trigger-right-click-using-pure-javascript - Simulate long click in JS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664703/simulate-long-press-in-javascript

Comment: Does this make sense?

Comment: The first answer doesn't work for me. 
The second one just seems to be a listener for a long press event. not a way to trigger the event.

Comment: Huh? The first answer is how you fire a click event in JS. --- The second isn't a listener, but how to emulate a long click. --- Both of these are what you've asked about. --- If something "doesn't work" consider asking a question just about that.