# How to show popup on button press/equivalent?

Tags: html, css, popup

How do I change or add any code in order to tap and hold to show the pop up, currently once I press the button the pop up window will appear, I want to change it to tap and hold.

```
<div id="ScenePop1">
   <a href="#login_form1" id="scene1">1</a>
   <a href="#x" class="overlay1" id="login_form1"></a>
   <div class="popup1">
        <h2>Scene 1</h2>
        <button id="store1">Store</button>
        <button id="del1">Delete</button>
        <a class="close1" href="#close"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/oajt5p28/

Answer (score -1):

This link come to elegant solution with the combination of jquery, jmobile and simpledialog2: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/05/23/Context-Menu-Example-with-jQuery-Mobile.

Or use could use html5 dialog element, and catch taphold event following this way:
[How to detect a long touch pressure with javascript for android and iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139225/how-to-detect-a-long-touch-pressure-with-javascript-for-android-and-iphone)