# Detect MacOS longpress key popup on textarea

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to detect when the popup key for selection is out on the textarea:

[image]

This one in the picture to be clear.

My current finding is that registering events as i did in the fiddle down does not help me finding something unique when the popup opens.

Why i need to detect the popup?
Because i have some event registered on the keydown that call a `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`. On firefox for example this kind of event handling stop the popup from working completely and so i need to disable my even handler when the popup is opened.

```js
var txt = document.getElementById('test');

txt.addEventListener('compositionupdate', console.log);
txt.addEventListener('compositionstart', console.log);
txt.addEventListener('compositionend', console.log);
txt.addEventListener('input', console.log);
txt.addEventListener('keyup', console.log);
txt.addEventListener('keydown', console.log);
txt.addEventListener('keypress', console.log);
```

```html
<textarea id="test" ></textarea>
```

Comment: Does this solve? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6139225

Comment: No it does not. I do not want to detect a longpress, i would like to understand if that popup is javascript detectable.

Comment: I don't think it is detectable by JS, as it is OS specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some months later, i realized how to handle it.

This was mainly to detect the use of this popup in fabricjs.
I stop playing with keyup and keydown and i delegated everything to the oninput event.
Now when any oninput events fires, i compare what i have in the textarea with my text var, plus i check the position of the cursor before and after and i detect the changes.

It works pretty good, but not, the popup is not detectable.