# Create a custom event like 'click' for longtap

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, dom-events

I want to make a custom event which I can use like

```
$('.entry').on('click', function().......
```

I need it for detecting a longtap for mobile devices. I want to call it like this:

```
$('.entry').on('longtap', function().......
```

I read a lot about creating events but the most ways are with bind and trigger. So is there a way to do this?

Comment: When should the `longtap` should trigger?

Comment: i have a table with many rows. i want to fire if the user longtaps on a row so that i can select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You may use one of the handmade solutions, provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139225/how-to-detect-a-long-touch-pressure-with-javascript-for-android-and-iphone).
2. You may attach it as [third-party script](https://www.cssscript.com/handle-long-press-tap-event-in-javascript-long-press-js/).
3. There is a special [taphold](https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/) event for jQuery Mobile.

Comment: i cant use jquery mobile because it does many weird things to my frontend - also if i only use the js file without the css. i'll have a look to the third party script. it seems a good solution.

Comment: i used the third party script which is very small and handy. i did some small modifications to fit my needs and so it works! Thanks to everyone!

Comment: I'm glad this helped!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to implement long tap:

```js
var clickStart;

document.getElementById("cool_button").addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  console.log('mouse down');
  this.clickStart = new Date().getTime();
});

document.getElementById("cool_button").addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  console.log('mouse up');
  if ((new Date().getTime() - this.clickStart) >= 1000) {
    console.log('this is a long tap');
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="cool_button">i'm a long tap button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript/27413909) , you don't need to create a custom event for longtap, you only need js timer and two already exsiting events like mouseup, mousedown:

```
var pressTimer;

$(".entry").mouseup(function(){
  clearTimeout(pressTimer);
  // Clear timeout
  return false;
}).mousedown(function(){
  // Set timeout
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("hi!")
  },1000);
  return false; 
});
```

I made an example for you

https://jsfiddle.net/sOoN92/74rbc2ph/