# JavaScript Web API: Handle long TouchEvent while retaining default behavior in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, touch, touch-event

In addition to `MouseEvent`s I'd like to use a "long" [`TouchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) of a single finger/digit/input for my application (change mode, e.g. to start drawing or select elements to manipulate), while retaining all default actions like clicking/tapping, scrolling/swiping and hold-for-context-menu or hold-to-select.

In other words:

1. a short touch (tap) should be analogous to a normal mouse click (usually emulated by browser)
2. (short) touch and move (swipe) should cause normal scrolling
3. a "longer" touch should be analogous to a mouse click-and-hold
4. consequent move events should not cause scrolling but are handled by the application
5. a long touch without move should cause normal secondary function (select, context-menu)
6. pinch and other multi-touch gestures should use default handlers (for now)

There is no "hold-to-select" or similar event to my knowledge, so I am attempting to implement this myself.

Detecting a "long" touch before drag is quite simple ([`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), e.g. [How to detect a long touch pressure with javascript for android and iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139225/how-to-detect-a-long-touch-pressure-with-javascript-for-android-and-iphone)), however, the initial `touchstart` already seems to trigger default event handlers, causing

- no scrolling (intended)

  - Chrome on Windows
  - Chrome on Android
- scrolling

  - Safari on iOS (iPhone)
  - Firefox on Windows and Android
- secondary functions

  - select (not intended if move occurs)

    - Safari on iOS (iPhone)
  - magnifier (not intended if move occurs)

    - Safari on iOS (iPhone)
  - context-menu (intended, when no move occurs)
  - Chrome on Windows: as intended (very long touch, no move)
  - Firefox on Windows: as intended (very long touch, no move)
  - Chrome on Android: none
  - Firefox on Android: none

on actual devices, despite `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` calls from touchmove.

- is there a "better" way already (an event I don't know about)?
- is it possible to retroactively affect these envents/handlers (revert/undo events?)?
- is there a way to determine the default actions (select, context menu) and the respective timeout (browser / OS implementation dependant)?

or

- will I have to re-implement the very low-level handlers myself and then create and emit the necessary events (keeping different browser implementations in mind)?

Here's a preliminary snippet for testing (feel free to improve/extend):

```js
let t = document.getElementById("t");
t.innerHTML += navigator.userAgent + '<br/>'; 

// timer
var timerid;
var touchduration = 500;
var longtouch = false;
function lt(e){
  timerid = undefined;
  longtouch = true;
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  ls("LONG");
}
function ct(){if (timerid)window.clearTimeout(timer); timerid = undefined;}

function ls(s){
  t.innerHTML += i + ' ' + s + '<br/>';  
  t.scrollTop = t.scrollHeight;
}

// log event
let i = 0;
let o;
function le(e){
  if (e.type!=o){
    ls( e.type + (longtouch?' LONG':'') );
    o = e.type;
    }
  i++;
}

// mouse
t.addEventListener("mouseenter",  e=>{le(e);});
t.addEventListener("mousedown",   e=>{le(e);});
t.addEventListener("mouseup",     e=>{le(e);});
t.addEventListener("mousemove",   e=>{le(e);});
t.addEventListener("mouseout",    e=>{le(e);});
t.addEventListener("mouseleave",  e=>{le(e);});

t.addEventListener("click",     e=>{le(e);});
t.addEventListener("dblclick",   e=>{le(e);});
t.addEventListener("auxclick",   e=>{le(e);});

// wheel
t.addEventListener("wheel",       e=>{le(e);});

// touch
t.addEventListener("touchstart",  e=>{le(e); 
  timerid = window.setTimeout(lt, 500, e);
  });
t.addEventListener("touchend",    e=>{le(e);
  ct();
  longtouch = false;
  });
t.addEventListener("touchmove",   e=>{le(e);
  ct();
  if (longtouch) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  });
t.addEventListener("touchcancel", e=>{le(e);});


t.addEventListener("drag",        e=>{le(e);});

t.addEventListener("scroll",      e=>{le(e);});

t.addEventListener("contextmenu", e=>{le(e);});
t.addEventListener("select",      e=>{le(e);});
```

```html
<div id="t" style="height:10em; max-height:100%; overflow-y:scroll; border: 1px solid green;"/>
```

Comment: It might be an issue in Firefox - Chrome handles it better (does not scroll page). Tested on Windows and Android.