# Detect "long press" on touch devices

Tags: javascript

I'm using `contextmenu` event to capture right clicks. On touch devices that event fired via "long press".

The problem I'm experiencing is that the `contextmenu` event doesn't fire on touch devices until touch is released. I could listen for `touchstart`/`mousedown` events and set timeout, but it won't be accurate since each device might have its own delay for `long press` activation.

So, is there a way accurately detect when `long press` is activated on touch screen devices? (On some devices there is haptic feedback when `long press` was activated)

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to read out the timeout for the `contextmenu` event, so you could [implement it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139225/how-to-detect-a-long-touch-pressure-with-javascript-for-android-and-iphone), without luck. But let me tell you, on most devices `contextmenu` fires without releasing the touch, so in most cases it should be fine to use the `contextmenu` event to get the desired result. What device / browser are you using?

Comment: Oh, yes, you are correct, just tested in Edge on Samsung phone it indeed fires without releasing touch. However, Edge devtools responsive mode on Windows OS doesn't fire until released.

Comment: Could be a bug in the devtools simulator. I'm pretty sure real devices won't have this issue, because how is the user supposed to know how long he/she needs to press for the context menu to show up? (Rhetoric question). I decided to post my analysis as answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comment section.

> On most devices `contextmenu` fires without releasing the touch, so in most cases it should be fine to use the `contextmenu` event to get the desired result.

This might be a bug in the DevTools of Chromium, since you tested with that. I recommend to simply use the `contextmenu` event.

In case the specific device really fires the context menu on touch release, the user expects the same behavior on your website/app, so it should be fine to go this route.